# Change making algorithm with limited notes and multiple amounts

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given multiple amounts to be given, and list of notes (you cannot repeat them). I need to find notes combinations to give away all amounts.

> For Eample: if notes are: `[1,1,5,6,6,8,8,10]` and amounts are `[15, 14, 16]`.
>
> The solution can be `{15:(10,5), 14:(6,8), 16:(1,1,6,8)}`

This is a variation of change-making problem as described [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change). Below is the code using dynamic programming for standard change-making problem, given V (set of infinite denominations) and C(the amount). How to modify it for non-repeating notes and multiple amounts. Also need the final combination for each amount.

```
def min_change(V, C):
    m, n = len(V)+1, C+1
    table = [[0] * n for x in xrange(m)]
    for j in xrange(1, n):
        table[0][j] = float('inf')
    for i in xrange(1, m):
        for j in xrange(1, n):
            aC = table[i][j - V[i-1]] if j - V[i-1] >= 0 else float('inf')
            table[i][j] = min(table[i-1][j], 1 + aC)
    return table[m-1][n-1]
```

**Update:**

Change making problem is NP-complete. There is detailed paper here http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter5.pdf Nonetheless there are solutions which are fairly optimal and which give results.

Answer (score 2):

It may actually be worse than NP-complete as @MissingNumber states. The subset-sub problem would ask *if a solution exists*. That problem is considered to be [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np_hard). Your question actually asks something more difficult, namely *how many solutions exist*? This kind of problem belongs to the [P# (P-sharp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P) complexity class, and I believe it is P#-complete, making at least as hard (and possibly much harder) than the NP-complete version.

Some examples from Wikipedia to differentiate the two classes:

> An NP problem is often of the form, "Are there any solutions that satisfy certain constraints?"

1. Are there any subsets of a list of integers that add up to zero? (subset sum problem)
2. Are there any Hamiltonian cycles in a given graph with cost less than 100? (traveling salesman problem)
3. Are there any variable assignments that satisfy a given CNF formula? (Boolean satisfiability problem)

> The corresponding #P problems ask "how many" rather than "are there any". For example:

1. How many subsets of a list of integers add up to zero?
2. How many Hamiltonian cycles in a given graph have cost less than 100?
3. How many variable assignments satisfy a given CNF formula?

Comment: I dont need the number of solution, just 1 feasible solution. It may be unoptimized, i.e, using more notes, but atleast it should give a solution, if it exists. Edited the question, to make it more verbose.

Comment: @jerrymouse Ofcourse you'll need find all the possible ways to get a particular sum , to obtain a feasible solution . See yoour case u sated that 14 (6,8) , suppose if your algo gave you 14 as (1,5,8) , then rest of the numbers may not promise you a valid set with the given count . So the no of solutions matters in this case .

Answer (score 0):

This is NP-complete problem, please find the optimal solution for this at :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem